# Twitters bootstrap modal in iframe popout of it

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In Twitter Bootstrap is the possibility to get out of the box Modal dialogs shown on a website.
But I'm using this in a existing webapplication, that uses a lot of iframes.
The problem is; if you open a TB modal inside a iframe, it shows centered inside that iframe. I want to show it modal over the current opened page. With the modal backdrop/shadown.
But how..? I tried "window.parent.parent.document.*", but then the content isn't shown.
[example](http://www.w3resource.com/html5/html5-editor/edit_html.php)

Comment: There are some useful suggestion here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/936

Answer (score 4):

I use helper method to inject/update modals. It works in your iframe scenario.

In iframe:

```
$(function() {
  window.parent.renderModal(".my-modal-class", "My modal content");
});
```

The renderModal needs to be avaiable in parent page scope. Here is the code for it:

```
function renderModal(selector, html, options) {
  var parent = "body",
      $this = $(parent).find(selector);

  options = options || {};
  options.width = options.width || 'auto';

  if ($this.length == 0) {
    var selectorArr = selector.split(".");
    var $wrapper = $('<div class="modal hide fade ' + selectorArr[selectorArr.length-1] + '"></div>').append(html);
    $this = $wrapper.appendTo(parent);
    $this.modal();
  } else {
    $this.html(html).modal("show");
  }

  $this.css({
    width: options.width,
    'margin-left': function () {
      return -($(this).width() / 2);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Very nice; Thanks!
But sometimes the modal dialog is in a iframe inside a iframe. So a window.parent.parent.renderModal() should be called then, a double parent. Isn't there a function to call the mooooosssst parent window?

Comment: @user1469734 Yes, `window.top` is the topmost parent. To check if you are the topmost window, you can do `var amiTop = window.top === window;`

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jquery it gets a little clearer.

On you iframe page (i have a button)

```
  $('#tasks-modal').click(function(){
        window.parent.renderModal('#taskModal');
  });
```

where you are passing the model id.   Note:  The modal code MUST be loaded on the top frame where you are calling it.

Then in that top frame you simply have:

```
function renderModal(selector) {
      $(selector).modal('show');
}
```

Works great.....